# why android navigation similar deep links for one destination not working correctly?

Tags: android, navigation, deep-linking, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

in one of my destinations, I have 3 `deeplink`s like this:

```
<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deeplink_one"
    app:uri="https://example.com/{first}/" />

<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deeplink_two"
    app:uri="https://example.com/{first}/{second}/" />

<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deeplink_three"
    app:uri="https://example.com/{first}/{second}/{third}/" />
```

and results are weird:

for `https://example.com/item1/`, placeholders fill like this:

```
first = "item1" // that is not weird
second = null
third = null
```

for `https://example.com/item1/item2/`, like this:

```
first = "item1/item2" // <---- that is not what I want
second = null
third = null
```

and for `https://example.com/item1/item2/item3/`, like this:

```
first = "item1/item2/item3" // <---- not wanted, too
second = null
third = null
```

What am I doing or expecting wrong?